# Owasp ESAPI class not discoverable as bean in spring

Tags: java, spring, esapi

I'm using ESAPI library to encode name variable in my code.And my project is implemented on spring.

ESAPI.encoder().encodeForSQL( new OracleCodec(), name);

```
    import org.owasp.esapi.ESAPI;
import org.owasp.esapi.codecs.Codec;
import org.owasp.esapi.codecs.MySQLCodec;
import org.owasp.esapi.reference.DefaultEncoder;
    import org.springframework.jdbc.core.support.JdbcDaoSupport;

    public class StringJdbcDao extends JdbcDaoSupport{


    public void execute(){
            BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sqlDDL));
                        try {
                            // read the first line, skipping any '--' comment lines
                            boolean firstLine = true;
                            StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();
                            for (String line = r.readLine(); line != null; line = r.readLine()) {
                                **line = ESAPI.encoder().encodeForSQL(new MySQLCodec(MySQLCodec.MYSQL_MODE), line.trim());**
                                getSpringJdbcTemplate().execute(line);
    }
    }
```

I get the below error.

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name
>   'org.sakaiproject.genericdao.test.GenericDaoTarget' defined in class
>   path resource [spring-jdbc.xml]: Invocation of init method failed;
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanInitializationException:
>   Initialization of DAO failed; nested exception is
>   org.owasp.esapi.errors.ConfigurationException:
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException SecurityConfiguration
>   class (org.owasp.esapi.reference.DefaultSecurityConfiguration) CTOR
>   threw exception.  at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1338)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:473)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
>     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:380)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:264)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:261)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:185)

Comment: You haven't shown the code you're using to configure Spring to use the library.  Also, it would be *much* wiser to rewrite the SQL to use PreparedStatements than to use the SQL encoder.

Comment: @avgvstvs i edit the question and added my code.

Comment: @avgvstvs im using SpringJdbcTemplate not PreparedStatements

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/15113610/557153

Comment: Will evaluate your question when I get home.  In the meantime, that link should show you how to do prepared statement with spring jdbc template

Comment: Yeah, the code you've got here is just where you're instantiating it.  I'm not seeing what you've done to set up the dependency injection for the ESAPI class.

Comment: I haven't done anything else.just calling ESAPI.encoder().encodeForSQL.I want to know how to set up dependency injection for ESAPI.Exaplain your solution with common example.I want to know any external library class to call as dependancy which not marked as spring bean type.

Comment: @avgvstvs I have edit the question.

Comment: Edit didn't help.  

https://dzone.com/articles/dependency-injection-an-introd